# Flow: How to annotate array of React.Fragments?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

How do you annotate React.Fragments in Flow?

In my JSX component I map array of some data that I need to turn to React.Fragments holding multiple HTML elements. I'm going for something similar to this:

```
// @flow
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const data: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
  return data.map((el: number, i: number) => {
    const isOdd = el%2 === 0;
    return (
      <Fragment key={i}>
        <span>{isOdd ? 'odd' : 'even'}</span>
        <span>{el}</span>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
};
```

This code is giving me flow error of "Missing type annotation for `U`.". It is fixable by using `data.map<any>`, but of course I would like to refrain from using that solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments

Comment: Which version do you use? Seems to work fine https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AEoCmAhgMa4A0oA3qAGLYkDmaRAdvgL6iTaxpQAcmykKQgNzIysdgGd8AYQFZ2HfAF5QACgCUoDQD5aiUKBnz8AExK4SALlDsArmgBGRbAG0AugdBeAIzUAEzUAMw+UmaiuM7Y7KA2dgB0aCQY2tpE0I4u7p7UKHmuHtj6RiZmZhYKoChyAPJWVv45AKQhBhpaAAzR1bHxidqm1WYAPIwsbJygANZEAJ4aNChchmPjk3IYJOyGa00toAD8wrAtQqCOQkQAbhxCXBPAu-ub29UT7wc0OS83nsDltvsBpqx1J9qroBlxdIguEA Anyway you can use `Node` type from react. https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-node